# Drawing a filled rectangle in C# .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, graphics, drawrectangle

I want to make a rectangle with a custom filled colour (background colour) and a line

```
private void FooMethod(Graphics graph)
{
   // Draw a simple rectangle in C#, not filled.
   Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 45);
   graph.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rect);
   
   // "Make"? a filled rectangle (it doesn't work)
   graph.FillRectangle(Brushes.White); // I don't know how to proceed to draw a filled rectangle.
}
```

But It doesn't work and I tried [this Microsoft post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-draw-a-filled-rectangle-on-a-windows-form?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) and what I have showed (I'm too lazy to show you the Microsoft code but you can see with the link.

(I don't have much time to write, sorry if it's too short)

Comment: Like the DrawRectangle, the FillRectangle needs a rectangle value, too.  It's easier to Fill the rectangle first, then draw it to get a border, if that's the intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fill first and draw after so it won't get drawn over

```
    void FooMethod(Graphics graph)
    {
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(5, 5, 100, 45);

        graph.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, rectangle);
        graph.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rectangle);
    }
```

if you have a more complex shape, I suggest you use a GraphicsPath

```
    void FooMethod(Graphics graph)
    {
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(5, 5, 100, 45);
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
        path.AddRectangle(rectangle);
        // add to the  path
        graph.FillPath(Brushes.White, path);
        graph.DrawPath(Pens.Black, path);
    }
```

Here is a path that includes a rectangle and an ellipse as a hole

[image: scr1]

```
    void FooMethod(Graphics graph)
    {
        using(GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath())
        {
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(5, 5, 100, 45);
            path.AddRectangle(rectangle);
            rectangle.Inflate(-5, -5);
            path.AddEllipse(rectangle);
            graph.FillPath(Brushes.White, path);
            graph.DrawPath(Pens.Black, path);
        }
    }
```

Comment: OK, I forgot about the GraphicsPath class... Always a stupid reason... Thanks!